# Finding position of an object in a nested array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the following array, how would I find the position of the product with id = 71?

```
[[[#<Product id: 71>, #<BigDecimal:x>], 0], [[#<Product id: 73>, #<BigDecimal:x>], 1]]
```

Alternatively, if I have `@product = Product.find(71)`, how would I then find that this object is associated with the number `0` and not `1` in the above array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array#index` with block, with block arguments deconstruction (here using symbols instead of your custom objects):

```
arr = [[[:a, :b], 5], [[:c, :d], 7]]
# => [[[:a, :b], 5], [[:c, :d], 7]] 
arr.index{|((a, b), c)| c == 7}
# => 1 
arr.index{|((a, b), c)| b == :a}
# => nil 
arr.index{|((a, b), c)| b == :b}
# => 0
```

If you are interested in particular element, rather than its index, just use `find` instead of `index` (block argument would be the same).